# Playwright error when using TikTokApi library

Tags: python, playwright

My task is to download a video from tiktok in Python. I read that TikTokApi can be used for this. I installed this library and its dependency - playwright of the latest version. When I try to execute this code:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

with TikTokApi() as api:
    for video in api.trending.videos():
        print(video)
```

This error occurs:
`playwright._impl._api_types.Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'S[A][m(a[oprand[1]],oprand[1])]')`

Initially when I installed the latest version of TikTokApi with pip - nothing happened. An empty python file was installed, in the end I had to download the library from github and install it manually. After the error, I tried to install the playwright version which corresponds to the release date of TikTokApi. In the end, the error did not occur, but I could not get any data.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/1012#issuecomment-1607264627) on GitHub might help you

Comment: Thank you! The error with playwright fixed it, but I still can't upload the video because I can't access it from the link.